# Automatic reload import React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dynamic, import

Currently,
I've made an axios common to calling API as:

```
export const API_LOCAL = axios.create({
    baseURL: process.env.REACT_APP_BASEURL,
    headers: {
        'Authorization': `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('token')}`,
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    timeout: 30000,
});
```

First time when I start to import and use file with this export as API_LOCAL, I'm not use the 'Authorization', the localStorage.getItem('token') is null. Then I'll get some data and set back to localStorage.setItem('token','SOME_SAMPLE_TEXT').

After that, when in another calling which use API_LOCAL, I think it's cached because the API_LOCAL with localStorage.getItem('token') is always null.

Could I set up for the dynamic reload import file to get latest data?
Thank you for any guides.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the best way to handle Bearer token is via interceptor.
You can do something like

```
axios.interceptors.request.use((config) => {
  const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
  if ( token != null ) {
    config.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${token}`;
  }
}
```

This way every axios request will be sent with your auth token